# Load table with selected DropDown value?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have 2 component, the main page has a drop down, when a user makes a selection, I want to pass that ID to the component that has the Table to show the data on it. Right, now, it's showing the data, however, it's appending to it, so I can see the data from of the previous selection as well as the new selection. How can I get it to show only the data for the selected value?

main component:

```
    useEffect(() => {
      getCustomers(custId)

    }, [custId]);

    const getCustomers = async (custId) => {
     //calls the API to load the drop down with a list of customers
    
    }

    const customerChange = async (e) => { 
       setCustomerId(e.target.value)
     }

    return {
      <div>
         <select id="customers" onChange={customerChange}> 
            <option value="0">Select Customer</option>
            {customer.map(data => (
                 <option value={data.customerId}>{data.CustomerName}</option>
            )}
      </div>

    }
```

The table component:

```
const customerNotes = ({ custId }) => {

    useEffect(() => {
       getCustNotes(custId)
    }, [custId]);

//loads the react data table

        const getCustNotes = async(custId) => { 
           custNotes.GetNotes(custId) //call to the API
              .then((response) => {
                 setCustNotes(response.data) 
              })
              .catch(e) => { console.log(e) }
        }
    }
```

what could be causing my data in the table not to refresh completely and append rows instead of doing a full refresh with the new item selected in the dropdown?

Comment: around code you need to use triple back quotes (or how are those things called) (`\``), not (`'`) quotes...

Comment: If you console.log the data, is it doubling there as well?

Comment: @Dave, no, only in the table. I can see the data in my JSON results just once. I even checked the LINQ query to see if it's coming out twice, and it's not.

Comment: If you can move the code to a sandbox, it'd be easier to poke around. We can't see how the table is constructed/rendered. And GetNotes() would be interesting to see.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `key` attribute on elements you generate using `map()` or similar. The key attribute must be unique. It was missing when you build your dropdown menu. Added here:

```
return {
  <div>
     <select id="customers" onChange={customerChange}> 
        <option value="0">Select Customer</option>
        {customer.map(data => (
             <option key={data.customerId} value={data.customerId}>{data.CustomerName}</option>
        )}
  </div>
}
```

If you are missing the `key` attribute on your table rows, it could cause weird behavior. (Possibly duplicate data appearing?). Make sure you have the key attribute in your table rows.

See also: [react key attribute](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Comment: That didn't fix it. I'm still seeing the data twice in the table, but once in the JSON coming back. I'm using the ReactDatatable

Comment: In my F12, I do see from time to time [ warning; encountered two children with the same key  '[ ID of selected value in dropdown]'. Keys should be unique....

Comment: The warning is probably because you have duplicate keys, because your data is duplicated. There is no obvious error in the code you've presented. You'll have to share more code. If you isolate the issue (e.g. on codesandbox.io) it'll be easier to debug. My next step would be to hard-code the array you're mapping to make the table, and assuming the issue goes away, undo that and hard-code the result coming from GetNotes(). (ie, simplify the problem and eliminate big chunks of code.)

Comment: I changed the key_column in the dataTable and it looks like it may have resolved the duplicate data issue. I'm doing more testing, if that fixed it, I'll post an update after some more testing